# Is there a limit on the payload in MQTT paho library?

Tags: c, mqtt, iot, paho

Anything over 600 bytes malforms the packet and it cannot be published. MQTTSerialize_publish ([library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c/tree/master/MQTTPacket/src)) returns the correct amount of bytes for the payload however (eg. 1260).

I can't see any apparent limit in the code or the MQTT standard.

This is how i call the function

```
unsigned char bufm[1500];
int bufmlen = sizeof(bufm);
rc = MQTTSerialize_publish(bufm, sizeof(bufm), dup, qos, retained, msgid, topicString[0], message, messageLen);
```

I get this in my console for a particular payload:

```
messageLen=580
sizeof bufm=1500
rc=600
```

The payload (bufm) is transmitted fine.

For a different payload:

```
messageLen=638 
sizeof bufm=1500
rc=658
```

And since the payload is larger than 600 bytes the payload (bufm) is now only 19 bytes and only contains some parts of the message array.
Notice how the rc is correct on both occasions.

Also there is enough memory where my pointer points to `unsigned char bufm[1500];`

---------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

yup.....
It was a stack issue. My pointer was pointing to the stack...so stack overflow

Sorry and thanks for the help.

thanks

Comment: Are you saying you've read somewhere of this behavior, or that you've observed this behavior in your own code? If the latter, can you show a minimum big of code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This sounds like a MTU problem. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69347021/edit) the question to show a minimum viable testcase that reproduces the probelm.

Comment: My guess is that in the publish code, you're either using a very constrained embedded thing with just 512 bytes allocated, or more likely: your publish code doesnt stay for long or run the loop for long enough after publish. So, the library is just publishing the first MTU and stopping. Show us your publish loop code.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop aren't 1500 bytes allocated in the buffer which is more than enough right? Also, what loop are you referring to? I just call this function to serialize the data and then send it via UART to a modem. thanks

Comment: The thing is the payload gets distorted right after the function call and there is no constraint since I've used bigger buffers for other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup..... It was a stack issue. My pointer was pointing to the stack...so stack overflow

Sorry and thanks for the help.

Comment: A good idea can be to compile/run your code with address/memory sanitizers. Then your code will crash with a "stack overflow error" for instance. I use "clang sanitizers" fyi